# jquery conflict with other jquery functions in wordpress/ php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, conflict

I am trying to set up jquery instant postcode search function [from http://ideal-postcodes.co.uk], I successfully added the fields on domain http://www.avada.creativeitechnologies.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/examples/example.html however the Postcode field is not showing up. If I move these files to entirely different domain [that is http://creativeitechnologies.com/test/examples/example.html], then the page is working fine. I am sure this is jquery conflicting issue but just can't get it right.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you tried [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)?

Comment: jquery not defined "http://www.avada.creativeitechnologies.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/libs/jquery/jquery.js"

Answer (score 1):

Reason is some of the file is not loading

```
  <script src="http://www.avada.creativeitechnologies.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>// This file not loaded 
  <script src="http://www.avada.creativeitechnologies.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/src/jquery.postcodes.js"></script> // This file loading
  <script src="http://www.avada.creativeitechnologies.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script> // This file loading
```

change the order of files (jquery is first)

```
<script src="http://www.avada.creativeitechnologies.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://www.avada.creativeitechnologies.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/src/jquery.postcodes.js"></script>
```